# Why is the base of Snoopy's dog house hidden when it flies?

Tags: analysis, the-peanuts-movie

Throughout [*The Peanuts Movie (2015)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2452042/), the base/bottom of Snoopy's dog house is never shown when he flies. It is outside the screen or hidden by another object.

For example, like this:
[image]

Or like this:
[image]

As seen in the trailer:

What is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: It's so we won't see the rig. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Snoopy isn't really flying. It's all in his head. As evident by him falling from cloud 9, as it were:

[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate? Why is hiding the base relevant, then?

Comment: It's relevant because if the base was visible it would indicate that it's actually happening.  By hiding the base, you can keep the "illusion" it's actually happening, but give the realism that it's not.  Such as when he falls from cloud 9 and lands in his bowl.

Comment: I just wish this was in the answer, is all...

Comment: BTW, this is also the case in every Peanuts strip involving the Sopwith Camel.  So, in a way you could considered the "hidden doghouse base" to be canon.

Comment: So it's like the spinning top in the movie 'Inception'...

Comment: @Walt I agree that that additional remark makes the answer clearer. I edited it in, the edit was approved, and then someone edited it out again. I'm not going to start an edit war over it.